# Is this prone to SQL injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, sql-injection

In my controller action, I have the following:

```
def index
    @articles = (params[:mine] == "true") ? current_user.articles : Article.search(params[:search])
    @articles = @articles.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
    @articles = Kaminari.paginate_array(@articles).page(params[:page]).per(25)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @articles }
    end
end
```

And in the model:

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search.present?
      where("category LIKE ? OR article_type LIKE ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

I understand that SQL injection would be possible if you use params directly in a query. Here, I'm passing params directly to the where query through `Article.search(params[:search])`. Is this prone to SQL injection? If it is, how can I make it more secure? I also have my doubts if I've written the controller code properly. If you have suggestions in refactoring the controller code, please do let me know and they'll be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your query, you should try to use the methods provided by `ActiveRecord` or go through `Arel` itself (your current method is fine though). This will ensure your SQL is properly escaped. If you don't want to go into details of `Arel` right now, you can use gems like [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) or [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where) (for older rails).

I highly recommend these gems for most of your query building needs. Anything more advanced you can write out directly using `Arel`.

I can't recall, if you can do `matches` (`LIKE`) directly out in basic `ActiveRecord.where` syntax, without the help of gem, yet. But you can definitely do this directly in `Arel`.

```
articles = Article.arel_table
articles = articles[:category].matches("%#{search}%").
  or(articles[:article_type].matches("%#{search}%"))
```

At this point you can do a `to_a` on `articles` or use `to_sql` and pass this to your `Article` model using `find_by_sql`.

```
Article.find_by_sql articles.to_sql
```

[will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/) has a `paginate_by_sql` method, and I would assume `kaminari` would have one as well (or at least I would think it would).

As for your controller code, I would pass any type of sorting option off to the database (this goes for your pagination as well), if you possibly can.

```
articles.sort('`articles`.created_at DESC')
```

The method your using now will grab "ALL" the [allowed] records then sort, then give back your `per_page` limit. Which kind of defeats the purpose of paginating at all, in this case.

At a minimum, try to refactor your current setup as:

```
@articles = (params[:mine] == "true") ? current_user.articles : Article.search(params[:search])
@articles = @articles.sort('`articles`.created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

As long as your passing around an `ActiveRelation` you can bind additional stuff to this due to the way Rails lazyloads it's queries to the database.

Comment: Thank you for providing this much detail. I'm not really sure if I want to go into Arel yet, but squeel does look appealing, I'll definitely check it out. By 'your current method is fine though', do you mean it's safe from injection? Can you explain that part a bit more if possible? thanks!

Comment: I knew something was wrong with the pagination, but my problem was I can't do .page() on an array, because the first line returns either an array or an active record relation. Do you know how I can handle this? And by passing the sorting option, do you mean I should pass it as a parameter instead and perform sorting on the model? Thanks.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection, can explain that a bit better than I.

Comment: Re: pagination, If at all possible, you want to have the database handle the pagination. If you are getting an ActiveRelation back, then  attaching kaminiari's `page` method should be fine. For your `find(:all)` statement, that runs the query directly, you want to remove that and just do `Article.page(2)`. This will use the lazyload method that Rails has.