# How can I avoid SQL Injection with this search feature in my Ruby on Rails website?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide! I've reviewed similar articles on Stack Overflow and these articles:

- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html
- [Is this prone to SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12127496/is-this-prone-to-sql-injection)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16994/Use-SQL-Parameters-to-Overcome-Ad-Hoc-Performance

However, I'm very new to MySQL and am working with a Ruby on Rails website that was created by another developer team. I'm just having trouble piecing together the different articles for my situation.

I know that there are SQL injection vulnerabilities in my code and that I need to use parameters. I'm just not sure how to do that with MY code. I've included portions of it below:

From my search.html.erb, the SELECT statement reads:

```
@office_matches = Masterlocation.paginate_by_sql("select * from mylocations where #      {search_string} order by nickname asc",  :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Then, in the search_controller.rb, it reads:

```
def results
@search_string = ""

@first_term = 'y'
      params[:search_terms_new] = "something in here so loop works"
    if params[:search_terms_new] != ""

# debugger

if params[:city] != ""
  @search_string << "and city like '%#{params[:city]}%' "
  if @first_term == 'y'
    @search_string = @search_string.gsub('and ', " ")
    @first_term = 'n'
  end
end

if params[:search][:state] != ""
  @search_string << "and state = '#{params[:search][:state]}' "
  if @first_term == 'y'
    @search_string = @search_string.gsub('and ', " ")
    @first_term = 'n'
  end
end
```

How should I alter this code to prevent SQL injection attacks?

Comment: Starting point: try building the query with Arel, which oughta handle escaping and such appropriately. (It'll probably come out prettier, anyway.)

Comment: Thanks, @Matchu. I may not go that route at this point since queries are already built and I'm looking for a quick fix to the code that's in place. I'll explore the gem for future builds, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should refactor your approach to use model scopes.

Start by putting scope based functions or scopes in your model.  Here is one of my models, I have excluded some of the bits that are not relavent to this example.  Below you will see I have two functions; one to search by account_grouping and one to search by account.

The account_grouping function is used with a dropdown box where the first item in the dropdown is "all", while the account search is a text search field.

```
class CostTypeAllocation < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :fiscal_year_id, :fiscal_period_id, :cost_centre_id, :account_grouping, :account_code, :account, :fixed_percentage,
    :marginal_percentage, :incremental_percentage,  :non_applicable_percentage

  scope :in_sort_order, order("fiscal_year_id DESC, fiscal_period_id DESC, account_code")

  # Allow for searching by Account Grouping
  def self.search_account_grouping(account_grouping)
    if account_grouping
      case account_grouping
      when 'all'
        scoped
      else
        where("account_grouping = ?", account_grouping)
      end
    else
      scoped
    end

  end

  # Search the text of the account
  def self.search_account(account)
    if account
      where("account LIKE ?", "%#{account.downcase}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Now the function in my controller that deals with searching.

```
class Admin::CostTypeAllocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def index
    @search_account_grouping = params[:search_account_grouping] || 'all'
    @search_account = params[:search_account]
    @cost_type_allocations = CostTypeAllocation.search_account_grouping(@search_account_grouping).search_account(@search_account).in_sort_order.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

  end
end
```

So no SQL in controller or parameters. everything encapsulated in the model where it should be.  Pagination is handled by the will_paginate gem.

---

In reply to your comment
It does not really matter where the code is, however it is good practice to keep all you data access in the model layer.

Your main problem is using #{params[:city]} in strings.  Anything the user enters in a parameter will be put in your SQL and therefore allow SQL injection attack.  where('city like ?', "%#{params[:city]}%") is safe as rails will filter out any SQL in the param before constructing the where clause.

Set up a scope for where city and where state just like the one I set up for where account; once you have those you can then just go model.cityscope(params[:city]).statescope(params[:state]) and rails will chain them together as needed.

I guess you need to put scopes in whatever models have city and state.

See the security guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Following on from your comment, i think this is what you might be looking for.

In your model

```
def self.search_city(city)
    if city
        where ("city LIKE ?", "%#{city}%")
    else
        scoped
    end
end

def self.search_state(state)
    if state
        where ("state LIKE ?", "%#{state}%")
    else
        scoped
    end
end
```

And in your controller

```
@collection_for_view = Model.search_city(params[:city]).search_state(params[:state])
```

In each case the search function will return the where filter if the parameter has been set or all records if it is blank.

Comment: Mark, thanks for your reply. Some follow-ups: 1) How do I know which model to use? 2) Should I just cut the code as-is out of the controller and paste it into the model? 3) Will doing this prevent SQL injection? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm still having a little trouble following. Is this correct? 

`if params[:city] != ""
  @search_string << "and city like '%#{params[:city]}%' "
 where("city LIKE ?", "%#{params[:city]}%")
 else
      scoped
  if @first_term == 'y'
    @search_string = @search_string.gsub('and ', " ")
    @first_term = 'n'
  end
end`

Or do I need something like this
`@search_string = :city, :state

def self.search_city(city)
    if city
      where("city LIKE ?", "%#{params[:city]}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end`