# Rails chaining queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am having difficulty with filtering optional query params.

```
def index
  @books = Book.where(nil) 
  @books = @books.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  @books = @books.location(params[:location]) if    params[:location].present?
  @books = @books.starts_with(params[:starts_with]) if params[:starts_with].present? 
end
```

I found an example very similar to this one online. My problem is chaining optional parameters. For example, what is I only want to filter for :status and :location or filter for :location and :starts_with? Not sure what to do...

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4480139/2835243). That should do what you're seeking to do.

Answer (score 2):

At this point you'll probably need to drop to pure [AREL](https://github.com/rails/arel) and pass those as params to a search method. Which gives some nice extra [predicates](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/predications.rb) and is more extensible

here's a down and dirty off the top of my head example of how you *could* do it with AREL. Its untested code though... it *shouldn't* be open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127653/793330) but I can't remember if AREL sanitizes matches queries. Also the AREL approach on matches is preferred to raw SQL as it should be DB agnostic.

```
class Book
  ... 
  # search class method via AREL
  def self.search(params = {})
     if params.respond_to?(:has_key?)
       # setup arel object for proper table
       books = Arel::Table.new(:books)

       if params.has_key?(:location)
         location_match = books[:location].eq(params[:location]) 
       end

       if params.has_key?(:status)
         status_match = books[:status].eq(params[:status]) 
       end

       # although if all you're doing is searching for a title
       # maybe you can deprecate starts_with column and search 
       # the proper column say... title
       if params.has_key?(:starts_with)
         title_match = books[:starts_with].matches("%#{params[:starts_with}%")
       end

       # return AREL query. Note this *should* be safe from [SQL injection][4]
       # via AREL sanitization but verify then trust. 

       # Choose one of the below
       # match on Any 
       where( location_match.or(status_match).or(title_match) )

       # match on ALL 
       where( location_match.and(status_match).and(title_match) )
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Or more complex setup but simpler approach is to use the [search kick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) gem and setup an [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) instance.

Also quick side note. Checking a Hash's keys with Hash#present? is a code smell. What happens if the checked object doesn't respond to the index method... It'll blow up with

```
(dev)> a = nil
=> nil
(dev)> a[:dave].present?
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

IMO You should more properly check that the hash itself exists and then use the ruby method has_key?(:some_key)...

```
(dev)> a = nil
=> nil
(dev)> a.present? && a.has_key?(:dave)
=> false
(dev)>
```

But then that's just me, your mileage may vary. Basically never trust ruby's types to be what you expect them to be.

Note in this method we set a default hash if none is passed so we can jump to the has_key? check, however it could still go away if we passed it something else, hence the respond_to? check on params.

Now when you call it in the controller (or model or wherever) you can call as such

```
@books = Book.search(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
def index
  @books = Book.scoped
  @books = @books.where(status: params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
  @books = @books.where(location: params[:location]) if params[:location].present?
  @books = @books.where(starts_with: params[:starts_with]) if params[:starts_with].present? 
end
```

But I am not sure about the `starts_with` attribute ...

Comment: Is there a reason why?

Comment: Also, isn't Book.scoped the same as Book.where(nil) ?

Comment: @codecalypso `Book.where(nil)` is the same as `Book.scoped` but I find `Book.scoped` less confusing than `where(nil)`. I don't understand your first comment : I don't see what you want me to justify.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been specific. I was asking why you weren't sure about the starts_with attribute.